# Excel - Sorting Decimal Values

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, decimal

I have a decision support system in Microsoft Excel for students which looks at their preparation for different modules and then ranks the modules in term of priority.

To do so, I generate an overall preparation score (formatted as a decimal NOT a string) for each module and then sort these. Based on sample data, it returns the following (as two separate columns obviously):

Module1 | 0.2953

Module2 | 0.3049

Module3 | 0.2815

Module4 | 0.0667

When I sort in ascending order numerically by the column on the right, I end up with:

Module3 | 0.2815

Module1 | 0.2953

Module2 | 0.3049

**Module4 | 0.0667**

It is all correct, par the fact that '0.0667' (and the subsequent 'Module4') should be on the top as it is the smallest number. Any idea what could be causing this and how I could solve it? I have a feeling that it is based on the formulas I used to generate the scores, which are all modifications for the specific modules of the following:

```
=($C16*$C$22)+($D16*$D$22)+($E16*$E$22)+($F16*$F$22)+($G16*$G$22)+($H16*$H$22)+($I16*$I$22)
```

However, I can't see how a specific formula could be causing an error for sorting when the values it is returning are correct and seem fine to be ordered.

Does anybody have any thoughts on what could be triggering this problem or if there was another way to sort to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better question for superuser rather than stackoverflow.

You could try changing the formula to `=SUMPRODUCT($C16:$I16,$C$22,$I$22)` but can't see why that would affect the sort.

Couple of things you can look at:

1) Number formatting. Double check you don't have something weird like `"0".000` in the number format for the cell in question

2) Referencing the worksheet name in the formula. Excel's sort doesn't work correctly if your formula references its own sheet name in the formula. e.g. if you're on Sheet1 and your formula is `=Sheet1!A16` then a sort will work differently to if it just said `=A16`